# How to delete a key and return the value from a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

When using PHP, I find myself writing code like this a lot:

```
$target = $_SESSION[AFTER_LOGIN_TARGET];
unset($_SESSION[AFTER_LOGIN_TARGET]);
return $target;
```

In Python, there is a `dict.pop` method that would let me do something similar in one statement, without a temporary variable:

```
return session.pop(AFTER_LOGIN_TARGET)
```

Is there a similar function or trick in PHP?

Comment: yeah, the array_pop of php removes/returns always the last element...

Comment: @Sebas but that's not what Python's `dict.pop()` function does, and is useless in the described case

Comment: Nice, I was looking for this but stumbled over [plain unset](/q/3053517) first.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't see a built-in function for this, but you can easily create your own.

```
/**
 * Removes an item from the array and returns its value.
 *
 * @param array $arr The input array
 * @param $key The key pointing to the desired value
 * @return The value mapped to $key or null if none
 */
function array_remove(array &$arr, $key) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $arr)) {
        $val = $arr[$key];
        unset($arr[$key]);

        return $val;
    }

    return null;
}
```

You can use it with any array, e.g. `$_SESSION`:

```
return array_remove($_SESSION, 'AFTER_LOGIN_TARGET');
```

**Short and Sweet**

With PHP 7+ you can use the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) to shorten this function greatly. You don't even need `isset()`!

```
function array_remove(array &$arr, $key) {
    $val = $arr[$key] ?? null;
    unset($arr[$key]);
    return $val;
}
```

Comment: @Eugene - `isset` will return `false` if the value is `null`, causing the function to leave the entry in the array.

Comment: I was talking about `array_key_exists`. `isset` would suffice.

Comment: @Eugene - So was I. `php -r '$x["foo"] = null; var_dump(isset($x["foo"]));'` outputs `bool(false)`. `array_key_exists` is slightly slower, but it returns `true` even if the key is mapped to `null`.

Comment: Unset can be placed after the if-statement. If the key to be unset doesn't exist, no error occurs, not even a notice. So @Eugene is right, isset suffices.

Comment: I posted a PHP7 solution 4 days earlier. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10898827/1000608

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is array_slice()

```
$target = array_slice(
    $_SESSION, 
    array_search('AFTER_LOGIN_TARGET', $_SESSION),
    1
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Variant of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10898827/1000608), using null coalesce.

```
function array_remove(array &$arr, $key) {
    $value = $arr[$key] ?? null;
    unset($arr[$key]);
    return $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why about a helper function? Something like that:

```
function getAndRemoveFromSession ($varName) {
    $var = $_SESSION[$varName];
    unset($_SESSION[$varName]);

    return $var;
}
```

So if you call

```
$myVar = getAndRemoveFromSession ("AFTER_LOGIN_TARGET");
```

you have what you asked for (try it a little, I haven't used php for many times :-])