# Is there a way to automatically unset a variable after accessing in php?

Tags: php, session

I am trying to display success or failure messages using session variables. I want them to be unset once the session variable once it is accessed. Is there some kind of PHP configuration where I can do it automatically with out writing any extra code?

I want something like this:

```
$_SESSION['message'] = 'print success';
echo $_SESSION['message'];
unset($_SESSION['message'])// I want this to be done automatically.
```

Could somebody help me with this?

Comment: use a ternary opeator and/or ajax

Comment: @Fred-ii- can you please provide me some sample code as i am new to php ?

Comment: You may want to destroy the session using  session_destroy()

Comment: @Samay i just wanted to do it  only a particular varaible. the exact requirement is like displaying messages which should expire after once they have been displayed :)

Comment: @Samay `session_destroy()` destroys all data registered to a session

Comment: @AniketSahrawat yeah it is but my requirement is different

Comment: There's an example of a ternary operator in here http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: @Jason - What you did in the code seems to work file. You have to unset it using the unset() function. You may write a generic function for the same..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a key and return the value from a PHP array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898699/how-to-delete-a-key-and-return-the-value-from-a-php-array)

Comment: is writing one extra line really an issue?

Comment: @Dagon wiriting a line is not an issue, but i wanted to make it reusable and efficient :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own session handler and have a custom method for that. I strongly suggest [Illuminate/Session](https://github.com/illuminate/session), though, and use it's `flash` feature which keeps items in flash bag for the duration of one request only.

```
class Session {
   public function read($str){
      return isset($_SESSION[$str]) ? $this->deleteAndRet($str) : null;
   }
   protected function deleteAndRet($str){
      $ret = $_SESSION[$str];
      unset($_SESSION[$str]);
      return $ret;
   }
}
```

Comment: so, anyway i should call some function right or is it going to be excecuted automatically ?

Comment: instead of `echo $_SESSION['message'];` you should then call `echo $session->read('message');` where `$session` is an instance of `Session` class. or you could define those methods as static and use `Session::read('message')` instead.

Comment: "unset($_SESSION['message'])// I want this to be done automatically." thats not automatic now is it ;-)