# PHP - Remove and return an element from an associative array

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a native PHP function for removing an element from an associative array, and returning the value?

Like `unset()` but with a return value, or `array_shift()` where you can specify the index to shift?

```
$element = unset($array['index']);

$element = array_shift($array, 'index');
```

I know it's easy to do, I'm just curious if there's an elegant one-liner for doing this.

Comment: Nope, the documentation does not show such a function.

Comment: You can buid a custom one with the and use it.

Comment: If you know the index, returning the value prior to unsetting should be a breeze. I'd use `array_splice()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking quickly at the [official PHP documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php), in the current version (7.2) doesn't have a function that removes and returns an element by the key.

But as you mentioned there are several ways to solve this problem. As you can see at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10898827/4214312